# ASP.NET Core 3.0 - Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.0, mediatr

We have windows service that hosts web api and does some calculation job in background.
From time to time we get exception:

```
2019-12-27 11:49:15.525 +01:00 [Error] [Serilog.Log.Write] Unhandled exception caught. Runtime is terminating : True
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at MediatR.ServiceFactoryExtensions.GetInstances[T](ServiceFactory factory)
   at MediatR.Internal.RequestHandlerWrapperImpl`2.Handle(IRequest`1 request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ServiceFactory serviceFactory)
   at MediatR.Mediator.Send[TResponse](IRequest`1 request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at DataProcessor.Enricher.ChangeTracking.LegacyDataChangeTracker.SendForEnrichment(TurbineTimeCounters turbineTimeCounters, Unit unit)
   at DataProcessor.Enricher.ChangeTracking.LegacyDataChangeTracker.<ProcessEventsAndHistData>b__29_1(Unit unit)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__139_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

We don't have any exceptions from built in DI on startup, thus dependencies are configured correctly.

I made investigation. MediatR's ServiceFactory is a delegate to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService`
 method.

`ServiceProviderEngineScope` is disposed at the time, when MediatR call's for it.
https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/DI/ServiceLookup/ServiceProviderEngineScope.cs

Any ideas why `ServiceProviderEngineScope` had been disposed before MediatR called it?

**MediatR** version 7.0.0.

**Asp.Net core** 3.0.

Comment: Are you injecting `IMediator` into your handler?

Comment: No, handler has logger and business logic classes.

Comment: Have you checked that you are awaiting all `async` calls?

Comment: Have you seen this comment on a similar GitHub issue: [link](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/440#issuecomment-236862811)

I had a similar issue with the IServiceProvider.CreateScope(). In very few occasions it throwed a System.ObjectDisposedException. With the hint from the link I got rid of it